# How do we use Django-allauth with lazysignup

Tags: django-sessions, django-allauth, lazy-registration

I'm using Django-allauth for social and simple login. I want that when a user who hasn't signed up or isn't logged in makes a shortlist of items, the shortlist is still present when the user signs up or logs in. So I'm using Django-lazysignup.

Right now, a new lazy_user is created everytime I'm not logged in with Facebook, or it gives me a "column user_id not unique" error. The shortlist is also not converted.

How do we integrate the two? Or how do we do this without using lazysignup?

Any help on this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/327f5b60f31e9b3db18d461266084a44f04888dc/allauth/account/adapter.py#L117

and here:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/327f5b60f31e9b3db18d461266084a44f04888dc/allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py#L40

Here, a new `User` instance is created for local and social users respectively. These adapter methods can be overriden, and instead of spawning a new instance they could be changed to return an existing lazy user instance.

With `django-allauth` out of the box you will probably run into the problem that you don't have access to the `request` instance here, but I am willing to adapt `allauth` to match your use case...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but Im still a bit confused as to how to override the adapter methods and integrate it with lazy-signup. Do you know of any working example or can you give me a brief about it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [custom user model (Django 1.5)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) tweaked in a way, so that it uses the session key as identifier for example.
Later on signup.. just fill in the username and/or email etc.

This could make sense if you want to save the lazy users interactions even if they do not sign up (e.g. for statistical usage). I have not tested this.. but it might work. :)